# Check special character `(tick) in foreach loop?

Tags: c#, telnet

I am working on a C# application, the purpose is to configure a wireless access point via telnet commands. The front end is built on WPF.

The problem is that there is a special character `(tick or negation) which I have to pass using C#. All other special characters are passing accurately except tick.

The telnet command for special characters which is predefined in access point is:

```
_apCommand = "set interface " + _inputWLAN + " ssid " + _apSSID + "\n";
```

The special characters need to pass in quotation marks("") like:

```
_apCommand = "set interface " + _inputWLAN + " ssid " + "\#" + "\n";
```

but for ` it needs to pass like:

```
 _apCommand = set interface  wlan0  ssid  "\`"
```

Above is the actual telnet console command all other special spcial characters are just passing in quotation marks but `(tick) needs (\)backslash too.
Here is my C# code:

```
string _apSSID = "";
      string _apSSIDOrignal = "";

      if (_inputWLAN == "wlan0")
      {
          _apSSIDOrignal = this.ConfigLibrarySSID;
          foreach (char c in _apSSIDOrignal)
          {

              _apSSID += "\"" + c + "\"";
          }


              {
                  if (this.ConfigLibraryVAP == VAP.vap0)
                      _apCommand = "set interface " + _inputWLAN + " ssid " + _apSSID + "\n";

                  else
                      _apCommand = "set interface " + _inputWLAN + (this.ConfigLibraryVAP) + " ssid " + _apSSID + "\n";
              }

          }
```

The whole story is for `(tick) sign all other characters are passing accurately.

Can anyone tell me how to to check and enter \ as the ` sign encounter in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this ...

```
"set interface" +  wlan0  + " ssid " +  "\\\`"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to use a literal string for that:

```
 _apCommand = "set interface  " + wlan0  + " ssid  " + @"`";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, there is a nice trick I like to use whenever I have to deal with multiple levels of special char escaping: I use the verbatim string specifier `@`.

`string tick = @"\'";`

This way you can be sure that exactly those characters are used as console input.
So no .Net language imposed string escaping is required.